# OpenMP task output

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I don't understand the following question:

Specify **four** possible outputs of the code when it is compiled with `-fopenmp` and executed with **two** OpenMP threads:

```
int x = 0; 
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp single
    {
        #pragma omp task
        {
            x++;
            printf("task 1: %d\n", x);
        }
        #pragma omp task
        {
            x++;
            printf("task 2: %d\n", x);
        }
    }
}
```

What "special" impact would the `-fopenmp` have on this?

Are these possible outputs:

1. task 1: 1, task 2: 2
2. task 2: 1, task 1: 2

What about other possible outputs?

Comment: Perhaps the most "special" impact of `-fopenmp` is that it enables processing of all the OpenMP `pragma`s in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two possibilities that you showed:

1. task 1: 1

   task 2: 2
2. task 2: 1

   task 1: 2

And

When the `x++` execute first in both tasks, and print the first task then the second:

3. task 1: 2

   task 2: 2

When the `x++` execute first in both tasks, and print the second task then the first:

4. task 2: 2

   task 1: 2

Comment: What about when `x++` executes simultaneously in both tasks and you get `task 1: 1` and `task 2: 1`, also in reverse order of tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Without `-fopenmp` the code is compiled into a sequential program (where all OpenMP pragma are ignored).

The two other possible outputs are coming from the case where the two tasks are executed *concurrently* (instructions interleaving). Indeed, although the two tasks are submitted sequentially in one *single* thread, each can be executed by different threads simultaneously (since there are no task dependencies nor critical sections). As a result, the two `x++` can be executed before the two `printf` (executed in any order). Such code is clearly  *unsafe* due to a **race condition**.